# What is the Bṛihat-sāma of Sama Veda that the Lord Shree Krishna mentions in BG 11.35 and where can I find it.?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, mantras, reference-request, sama-veda, hymn

I am looking for this hymn cited by the Lord Shree Krishna. This is not Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, since it is linked to the Yajurveda.

Please, help me, I am looking for [this](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/10/verse/35).:

> बृहत्साम तथा साम्नां गायत्री छन्दसामहम् |
> मासानां मार्गशीर्षोऽहमृतूनां कुसुमाकर: || 35||
>
> bṛihat-sāma tathā sāmnāṁ gāyatrī chhandasām aham
> māsānāṁ mārga-śhīrṣho ’ham ṛitūnāṁ kusumākaraḥ
>
> BG 10.35: Amongst the hymns in the Samaveda know me to be the Brihatsama; amongst poetic meters I am the Gayatri. Of the twelve months of the Hindu calendar I am Margsheersh, and of seasons I am spring, which brings forth flowers.

[Bṛihat-sāma](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/brihatsaman) is mentioned here in the BG, but it doesn't show any citation from the samaveda.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It's clearer now.